# Python/Psychopy: Logging mouse click locations

Tags: python, psychopy

Using the code below, I'm trying to open a window for 10 seconds, have the user click anywhere on the screen as many times as they wish, and I want to log the mouse click locations. Every time the user clicks within the window (i.e. myMouse.getPressed) occurs, I'm appending the click location to a list (mouse_click_locations[]). However, the list is being appended with the same click location many times, on every frame. I want to append the click location to the list once, and no more until another click is initiated. I thought that adding 'myMouse.clickReset()' at the end of each frame would do this, but it doesn't make a difference.

After 10 seconds, I want the list to be populated with one location (x,y coord) for each mouse click initiated.

```
from psychopy import visual, core, gui, event, sound

win = visual.Window([800,600],color=(1,1,1), colorSpace='rgb', 
rgb=None, allowGUI=True, monitor='testMonitor', 
units='deg', fullscr=False)

myMouse = event.Mouse(visible=True,win=win)

refresh_rate = 60.0
default_time = 10

time_window = default_time * refresh_rate
time_window = int(time_window)

running = 1
while running:

    mouse_click_locations = []

    for frame in range(time_window):

        mouse_loc = myMouse.getPos()
        mouse_click = myMouse.getPressed()

        if mouse_click:
            mouse_click_locations.append(mouse_loc)

        win.flip()
        myMouse.clickReset()

    running = 0

win.close()

print mouse_click_locations
```

Could someone help me achieve this? am I using myMouse.clickReset() incorrectly?

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: Your question was also asked and answered at https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/logging-mouse-click-locations/2566 PsychoPy is a small community: please don't waste people's time by duplicate posting.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see a problem given that it's two separate websites. I took multiple perspectives as being a good thing. WIll refrain in future.

Comment: No problem, the comment was intended more as a guide to future posters, sorry if it seemed more like a rebuke. The same people tend to provide answers on each site, so we tend to prefer that people choose the most appropriate venue and just ask there. SO is good for code-based questions with definite answers, discourse.psycho.org more for the graphical Builder interface, and/or questions that need more of a dialog rather than a single question/answer format.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense! Cheers Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the script checks the mouse state for every iteration in your frame-loop; i.e. 60 times a second. As you say, you only want to get a single event for each mouse-down. Here's one solution where you simply halt the script until all buttons are released. Also note the use of `any` to explicitly check all buttons.

```
# Record mouse position if a key is pressed
if any(myMouse.getPressed())  # Any button pressed, no matter which
    mouse_click_locations.append(myMouse.getPos())

# Wait until all buttons are released
while any(myMouse.getPressed()):
    pass
```

No need to use `mouse.clickReset`. As a small comment, you do not update visual stuff on the screen, so you do not need to include `win.flip` in the loop. Because it waits for the next monitor update, it effectively rounds off reaction times (if you need these) to nearest 1/60 second interval. This, and relying a bit on defaults, would also simplify the script a great deal:

```
default_time = 10

from psychopy import visual, core, event    
win = visual.Window(color='white', monitor='testMonitor', units='deg')
myMouse = event.Mouse(visible=True, win=win)
clock = core.ClocK()

# Collect unique click events before time runs out
mouse_click_locations = []
while clock.getTime() < default_time:
    # Record mouse position if a key is pressed
    if any(myMouse.getPressed())  # Any button pressed, no matter which
        mouse_click_locations.append(myMouse.getPos())

    # Wait until all buttons are released
    while any(myMouse.getPressed()):
        pass

print mouse_click_locations
```

Comment: Thank you for your very informative and helpful response, Jonas. For some weird reason, I have a fixation with for loops. Your while loop method seems much nicer.